# Material-UI Theme const concatenation

Tags: material-ui

I am using const in my material-UI theme in order to define colors
for example

```
const tableHeader=grey[400]
```

in order to use semantic constant names I want to create several constants and give them the same color
for example somthing like

```
const tableHeader, borderDefault = grey[400]
```

is there any such way
(the eaxmple above don't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you should assign value to every variable separately.

But you can think of choosing another data structure to store color variables, smth like

```
const THEME = {
  borders: grey[400]
}

const tableHeader = THEME.borders;
const borderDefault = THEME.borders;
```

Answer (score 2):

apart from [Maryja Piaredryj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199454/11222282) answer, there's another way. Store these colors in the material-UI theme, and then use this using `makeStyles` or `useTheme`.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    custom: {
        palette: {
            borders: grey[400]
        }
    }
});
```

Now use this in `makeStyles` as a regular theme property

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    borderStyle:{
      borderColor:theme.custom.palette.borders;
    }
}));
```